# Any ideas for automatic initial/scripted configuration of a NetApp?

Tags: scripting, netapp

The background is to make a solution where we can automate as much as possible the building up of ‘pods’ that include server/network/storage and that will be built at remote sites.

In an ideal world would be that we create a single management server which is preconfigured with DHCP/TFTP/or whatever. This management server is racked with a CISCO UCS, FAS31x0, etc. at a build site and is then transported to the final customer site where on power it almost configures itself, or at least bootstraps itself far enough that a remote skilled 'expert' can complete the setup of the pod.

Ideas (doesn't have to resemble 100% of the above) would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any Kickstart equivalent for ONTAP. However, with a small amount of manual bootstrapping, you should be able to do *nearly* everything else by aide of the API. Often referred to as ONTAPI.

You can see a full list of the methods and corresponding CLI commands that are exposed in the [ONTAP SDK](http://communities.netapp.com/docs/DOC-1110) documentation. Bindings are available for the usual programming languages. There are also [Python bindings](http://communities.netapp.com/message/9896) - which although still unofficial, I can assure you that they work extremely well.

Answer (score 0):

TFTP to provision, then the unix command `expect` to connect via the CLI to finish the configuration.

Perhaps you can make a script to generate the expect script with the correct client information.